# KSS Installtion and Setup

Tags: css, ruby, rubygems, kss

Can someone outline some step by step instructions on how to set KSS up on my local computer?

I've been reading a lot of articles and none of them show a working demo. And they also assume I'm a ruby expert.

I'm expecting to see an html page and some sort of auto-generated documentation page.

I've installed and used gems before but I am by no means an expert. So assume I'm a total noob.

Assume I have the following folder structure:

C:Projects/MySite

- index.html
- sass
- css
- js

I did this:

```
gem install kss
```

I get confused here though:

```
styleguide = Kss::Parser.new("#{RACK_ROOT}public/stylesheets")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KSS doesn't have a native outputer. The example that confused you should be run in an Ruby interpretive shell (`irb` for example, which is installed by default with ruby).

So, go to your command line, type irb, and then type that line into the resulting shell, replacing `"#{RACK_ROOT}public/stylesheets"` with `"C:/Projects/MySite/css"`

If you want a nice navigable web page, see the example Sinatra app.

Comment: Does it have to be css or can the documentation be generated from the sass folder?

Comment: Yes, and it actually supports multiple paths as well, so `Kss::Parser.new("C:/Projects/MySite/css","C:/Projects/MySite/sass")` should work